# Communication between .dll and .exe

Tags: c++, video, dll, exe, communication

My project is structured in this way:

1. Dll calls an .exe
2. The .exe start recording a video stream from camera.
3. Another Dll is called and it sends a signal to the .exe to stop recording, and to save the video.

The first step is easy to implement:
I can simply call the .exe from the dll by ShellExecute or CreateProcess.

The second step is also easy:
on the internet there are lot of possibility for C++ video recording.

The third step is the problem, how do I say to the .exe to stop recording?
The .exe could wait for a specific signal?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look into that http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/

Answer (score 0):

Exe could create a mutex (or the dll calling the exe... you should know better when and where to create it, it's your project). Then, the dll in step 3 could open that same mutex and set it to a signal state. Exe would wait for that signal and stop the recording.

Comment: Or I could set the .exe to wait for the WM_CLOSE signal, is this a good idea?

Comment: I wouldn't use windows messages for that. Even if you go that way, maybe a custom message instead of WM_CLOSE? If that recording application has a window, you have to stop the recording before you close the application anyway...

Comment: No, it doesnt have a window. What kind of signal should I use?

Comment: As I said in my answer, I would use mutex. Search in MSDN for CreateMutex/OpenMutex/ReleaseMutex/WaitForSingleObject etc... Create a named mutex and use it. If you pass NULL for SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, the mutex will get a default security descriptor. If that will be a problem for you, create your own security descriptor.